# Error: A required parameter (id) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /location/[id]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

im working on a next.js and mongodb website and im following this tutorial exactly but with different files/variable names. i keep running into this error when trying to access the dynamic page : Error: A required parameter (id) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /location/[id]

tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFuwkrseXVE&ab_channel=Academind       Just before 2 hours 40 min

PS deleted db info for security reasons

```
export async function getStaticPaths(){
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(''); ////////// username and password here for mongo db and db name
    const db = client.db();
   
    const destinationsCollection = db.collection('destination');
    const destinations = await destinationsCollection.find({},{_id: 1}).toArray();
    client.close();
    return {
        fallback: false,
        paths: destinations.map((destination) => ({ params: {destinationId: destination._id.toString()},
    })),     
    };
}
```

Comment: What is the name of your page file where this function is located?

Comment: Your page is `/location/[id]` so you need to return an `id` field in the `params` objects, i.e. `{ params: { id: destination._id.toString() } }`. The param you use in the dynamic path matters.

Comment: Thank you so much juliomalves. The issue was that i had destinationId instead of just id

Answer (score 5):

Your page is `/location/[id]` so you need to return an id field in the params objects, for example:

```
{
    params: {
        id: destination._id.toString()
    }
}
```

The param you use in the dynamic path matters

in your page location e.g. `/location/[anythingInside]` you need to ensured whatever is inside your params is same with the dynamic name file which is  what inside the braces[] you created e.g. should like this:

```
{
    params: {
        anythingInside: data.id.toString()
    }
}
```

Whatever you used when creating the file must be same with the data in the param, for example:
`path/[anythingInside]` and `params: { anythingInside: { data }}`
remember `anythingInside` must be same with what is inside `params`.

Answer (score 0):

NextJS is very meticulous with its data fetching functions and you have to be very careful with the way that you return parameters with getStaticPaths() in dynamic routing pages. I believe the problem here is that when you return "params", you store the id of your data (destination._id.toString()) into a JSON variable called "destinationId". However, since the page is called "[id]", Next will be expecting an "id" JSON variable inside of "params". So your final code should look something like this:

```
export async function getStaticPaths(){
const client = await MongoClient.connect(''); ////////// username and password here for mongo db and db name
const db = client.db();

const destinationsCollection = db.collection('destination');
const destinations = await destinationsCollection.find({},{_id: 1}).toArray();
client.close();
return {
    fallback: false,
    paths: destinations.map((destination) => ({ params: {id: destination._id.toString()},
})),     
};
```

}

Hopefully this solves the issue!